# MD5 passwords from MS SQL to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

We need to move a client over from a .Net solution where all MD5 passwords are stored in an MS SQL db to a Magento MySQL database. After much Googling, it seems we cannot decrypt the passwords without a lot of effort.

What we would then like to know is, can one copy the MD5 passwords as is from the MS SQL db to a MySQL db and expect it to work?

We have asked for sample data of customers to test this but not sure when we will be getting it.

Answer (score 2):

If the hashing algorithm and salt match, then a direct copy *SHOULD* work.

- [Magento admin password reset using md5, why?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/33177/magento-admin-password-reset-using-md5-why/33180#33180)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240852/is-it-possible-to-decrypt-md5-hashes